# Indexes on BigQuery Table

Tags: cloud, google-bigquery

I have a use case in which we have a few tables in BigQuery.
Now I want to implement an index on one of the columns in the BigQuery table.
But I am not finding enough documentation to do that. I found a few blogs and posts mentioning BigQuery doesn't support indexes.
Please help me find a blog or post which can help me in implementing index on BigQuery. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google BigQuery Underlying Architecture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745300/google-bigquery-underlying-architecture)

Comment: It would help if you will describe why you need indexes, i.e. what shape your queries will look like. There could be some other mechanisms in BigQuery (either manual or automatic) which could result in performance that you would expect from traditional indexes in database.

Comment: Hi Mosha, in my usecase we have some 5lakhs of record as of now which we are displaying in a UI based on the user selection (includes pagination also). These selections are based on the 8 different columns in the same table. As of now our queries are giving satisfactory result, but i was worried in future as the number of records increases say some 10-100 times of what i am having now. So was thinking to find a way to implement index or some alternative to improve the performance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

2019 update: Check out how c[lusters improve your querying times and data scanned](https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b):

- https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b

---

As stated in the comments this question is associated with "how would BigQuery deal with my data if it was a 100 times larger". When dealing with traditional databases an index is the right solution, but BigQuery is different: As data size grows, BigQuery adds more servers to the mix - keeping performance almost constant.

In other words, as your data grows you should expect costs to increase linearly, with performance staying almost constant. No indexes needed. And this is one of the big reasons why people choose BigQuery for their analytical workloads.

(It all depends on your specific use case of course, please test these assertions and report back!)

Comment: Thanks Felipe for your inputs. Will do the test using more and update here.

Comment: Hi Felipe, can I extrapolate from this answer that big query only gives you performance gain when you are dealing with data sets above a certain size?  For example, I currently have 80 million records in a table, and a table scan seems to complete in about 6 seconds, which is slower than various methods I could use on my laptop.  But if I had, say,  800 million records, it would still be about 6 seconds on BigQuery?

Comment: @Hexatonic - yes! What kind of scan are you running? I've seen a billion rows in 2 seconds, for example.

Comment: I'm also seeing poor performance in BigQuery where an index would be the solution in a relational DB. For example, searching ~50 million rows for a specific column value (WHERE myColumn = "searchvalue"). What other solutions might there be?

Comment: CAUTION: without an index your WHERE clause (even with a LIMIT!!) will attempt to scan the full table till the condition is satisfied. Depending on your table size, this can be one hell of a costly query!! Carefully consider placing LIMIT into an unconditional subquery and then a WHERE clause in the main query. However, this may not return all rows you are looking for ;)

Comment: Oleg - this is BigQuery. Everything is a full table scan.

Comment: "Full table scan all the time" is a poor solution.  Just because they have the processing power to do it in near-constant time doesn't mean they should, especially when they're billing us for it.  All modern column stores have methods for intelligently limiting the scan range on queries (indices, partitions, bloom filters, etc.) to minimize the IO and computational burden on queries.  Failure to implement any such features makes BQ unsuitable for a many use cases (high query volume / low data footprint) for which it would otherwise be a great solution.

Comment: @T3am5hark - you're replying to a 2017 comment. Queries run much better with clustered tables now. Did you read the update I left at the start of this answer?

Comment: Thanks for the update - that's a significant improvement for sure, I'll do some experimentation with clustered tables.

Answer (score 2):

The close you can get for "index" in BigQuery is [Partitioned Tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables). Currently it only supports partition by date though.

> A partitioned table is a special table that is divided into segments,
>   called partitions, that make it easier to manage and query your data.
>   By dividing a large table into smaller partitions, you can improve
>   query performance and reduce the number of bytes that are billed by
>   restricting the amount of data that is scanned. BigQuery offers
>   date-partitioned tables, which means that the table is divided into a
>   separate partition for each date.

Answer (score 2):

You can create indexes in bigquery table using Clustering order parameter available in advanced options while creating table.This clustering option is only available for Partitioned tables.
Follow the below link for additional details:
[link to google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-clustered-tables)

Comment: In 2022, "Clustering can be used on both partitioned and non-partitioned tables" (quoted from the console).

Answer (score 1):

Besides partitioning one could as well use multiple tables, eg each with a day's amount of data. BigQuery can query a maximum of 1000 tables at once, so that should cover most cases and let's you keep costs constant.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery now supports the creation of search indexes and a SEARCH function. This enables us to use Google Standard SQL to efficiently find data elements in unstructured text and semi-structured data.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/search-intro