# Is there any faster and less resource hungry query for same purpose?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with 50+ millions records with this structure:

```
sku STRING,
sale_net STRING,
sold_amount FLOAT64,
dt DATE,
is_promo BOOL
```

I need to select from it records with `sku` and `sale_nets` that had `is_promo = true` at least once.

For example if table have only 3 records:

```
sku1 sn1 123 01.01.2018 false
sku1 sn1 456 02.01.2018 true
sku2 sn1 321 01.01.2018 false //this sku-sale_net pair don't have is_promo = true records at other dates
```

Only first two should be selected by my query.

I write this query:

```
select * 
from src_tbl tbl1 
where (select count(*) 
       from src_tbl tbl2 
       where tbl1.sku = tbl2.sku 
         and tbl1.sale_net = tbl2.sale_net 
         and is_promo = true) > 0;
```

But it fails to execute on larger databases because of resource over use:

```
Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 105% of limit. Top memory consumer(s): aggregate functions and GROUP BY clauses: 93% other/unattributed: 7%
```

Is it possible to optimize my query and how?

Comment: What index do you have in your table?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - Sorry, I am not and SQL guy and probably can't answer you correctly.
If you ask about each record unique GUID, then there is none.
And if you ask about something else, then I don't know.

This is not my database, but I need to query it and can't change it.

Comment: An [index](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp) in db work similar to an index in a book. Allow you search thing much faster than scaning the whole book. But you need to be able to modify the table to create a new index. Without an index and you probably need a proper composity index your query wont improve the perfomance.

Comment: I just read bigquery doesnt need index as usual db. so maybe my comment doesnt work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28600228/indexes-on-bigquery-table

Comment: This question was 40 views and 5 answers. Well done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * 
FROM `project.dataset.src_tbl`
WHERE (sku, sale_net) IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT AS STRUCT sku, sale_net 
  FROM `project.dataset.src_tbl`
  WHERE is_promo
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this also results in resource over limit usage error.

Comment: is there any from supplied answers actually addresses  resource issue for you  - would be great to know :o)

Comment: I trying to use that `window` thing query now to test if it working. Then will try Juan Carlos Oropeza solution. I were testing most easy queries till now.

Comment: None of the answers solved resource usage issue, but every one is better then mine.
But you showed me how to do multicolumn `IN` check that is very useful for me in future.

Comment: glad, it helped at least somehow!

Comment: Well that is weird. If you keep getting resource usage error maybe there is a setting on the server you have to check. Because 50 millions rows isnt really that big

Answer (score 2):

In general, an exists clause will be better than using a count() for this type of query since that means the db knows it can stop working after finding one matching record, something like this might work:

```
 select * 
 from src_tbl tbl1 
 where exists (select 1 
               from src_tbl tbl2 
               where tbl1.sku = tbl2.sku 
                and tbl1.sale_net = tbl2.sale_net 
                and tbl2.is_promo = true);
```

If this still doesn't work, you can try avoiding having a correlated subquery at all, something like:

```
 select * 
 from src_tbl tbl1 
 where tbl1.sku in( (select tbl2.sku 
               from src_tbl tbl2 
               where tbl2.is_promo = true
               group by tbl2.sku ) );
```

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, I still getting same error about resource usage. Looks like I need something completely different if that even possible.

Comment: Can you move your data to a cluster table?

Comment: @TamirKlein - probably no. This is not my database and all I can do is to query it.

Answer (score 2):

How about using window functions?

```
select * 
from (select t.*,
             countif(ispromo) over (partition by sku, sale_net) as num_promos
      from t
     ) t
where num_promos > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from src_tbl tbl1 
where exists (select * from src_tbl tbl2 
where tbl1.sku = tbl2.sku and 
      tbl1.sale_net = tbl2.sale_net and 
      tbl2.is_promo = true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this work for you as I realize bigquery work different to regular db. But I will give my suggestion anyway.

First try to find which sku have promo.

```
select sku 
from src_tbl
group by sku
having COUNT( case when is_promo then 1 end) > 0
```

If that work try using a partial result or save it as a temp table

```
SELECT *
FROM src_tbl
WHERE sku IN (  select sku 
                from src_tbl
                group by sku
                having COUNT( case when is_promo then 1 end) > 0
              )
```

The difference is you only do on full table scan to find all the sku with promo and then another full table scan to return the rows with matching sku. Instead of do a full scan for each row to find if that one has a promo or not.

Comment: Thank you, I will think what is possible to do for this.

Comment: Just test it. If you can get the first query to work you will have part of the solution and the second query will be easier.

Comment: First query worked. I got the basic idea behind this logic and building new query now. I hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Joining should work, it's implemented more efficiently than `WHERE IN`type queries:

```
WITH promo_sku AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT sku, sale_net
  FROM `project.dataset.src_tbl`
  WHERE is_promo = true
)
SELECT * 
FROM src_tbl tbl1 
JOIN promo_sku ON promo_sku.sku = tbl1.sku AND promo_sku.sale_net = tbl1.sale_net
```