# how to create partition and cluster on an existing table in big query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In SQL Server , we can create index like this. How do we create the index after the table already exists? What is the syntax of create clusted index in bigquery?

```
CREATE INDEX abcd ON `abcd.xxx.xxx`(columnname )
```

In big query, we can create table like below. But how to create partition and cluster on an existing table?

```
CREATE TABLE rep_sales.orders_tmp PARTITION BY DATE(created_at) CLUSTER BY created_at AS SELECT * FROM rep_sales.orders
```

Comment: BigQuery does not have indexes - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28600228/indexes-on-bigquery-table) out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Indexes on BigQuery Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28600228/indexes-on-bigquery-table)

Comment: CREATE TABLE rep_sales.orders_tmp
PARTITION BY DATE(created_at)
  CLUSTER BY created_at 
  AS 
    SELECT *
      FROM rep_sales.orders

Comment: Looks like there is partition and cluster. But how to create partition and cluster on a existing table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Sergey Geron mentioned in the comments, BigQuery doesn’t support indexes. For more information, please refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/bigquery-data-warehouse#maintenance).

An existing table cannot be partitioned but you can create a new partitioned table and then load the data into it from the unpartitioned table.

As for clustering of tables, BigQuery supports changing an existing non-clustered table to a clustered table and vice versa. You can also update the set of clustered columns of a clustered table. This method of updating the clustering column set is useful for tables that use continuous streaming inserts because those tables cannot be easily swapped by other methods.

You can [change the clustering specification](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-clustered-tables#modifying-cluster-spec) in the following ways:

- Call the `tables.update` or `tables.patch` API method.
- Call the `bq` command-line tool's `bq update` command with the `--clustering_fields` flag.

**Note:** When a table is converted from non-clustered to clustered or the clustered column set is changed, automatic re-clustering only works from that time onward. For example, a non-clustered 1 PB table that is converted to a clustered table using tables.update still has 1 PB of non-clustered data. Automatic re-clustering only applies to any new data committed to the table after the update.